# error in node.js sometimes works fine, other times errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I'm using node.js, When I run my code, sometimes it runs fine, then every so often I get this error below, it seems to be a problem with the array (The undefined pops up in random parts of the array, sometimes its near the end of the console.log, other times (like below) its at the very beginning. charts/+symbol+.json is being updated constantly via a WebSocket, which may be causing the error, if the file is in the process of being updated when I'm trying to read it if so is there another way around this? to be able to read a file currently being updated?

```
POABTC  rsi 52.63
ZILBTC  rsi 48.63
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I cant seem to figure out why? seeing as sometimes it will run fine? my code is below:

```
setInterval(checkPairs, 300000);
checkPairs();    
function checkPairs() {
  var RSI = require('technicalindicators').RSI;
  const fs = require('fs');
  var Twit = require('twit');
  var config = require('./tconfig');
  var T = new Twit(config);
  var message = [];
  var theLoop = ['LTCBTC', 'LTCETH'];
  for (i = 0; i < theLoop.length; i++) {
    var symbol = theLoop[i];
    var data = fs.readFileSync('charts/' + symbol + '.json');
    var CurrentPair = JSON.parse(data);
    var prices = [];
    var period = 14;
    var lowTotal = [];
    var closeTotal = [];
    var rsiArray = [];
    for (var item in CurrentPair) {
      prices.push(Number(CurrentPair[item].close));
    }
    var newRSI = [];
    newRSI = RSI.calculate({
      period: period,
      values: prices
    });
    var rsiResult = newRSI[newRSI.length - 1];
    console.log(symbol + "  rsi " + rsiResult);
    if (rsiResult <= 23) {
      var twitMessage = "RSI is LOW (" + rsiResult + ") ";
      var splitSymbol = "";
      if (symbol.includes("BTC", 3) || symbol.includes("BTC", 4) ||
        symbol.includes("BTC", 5) || symbol.includes("BTC", 6)) {
        splitSymbol = symbol.replace("BTC", "");
      };
    }
  }
}
```

sample of the .json file

```
[
{
    "open": "0.21320000",
    "high": "0.21320000",
    "low": "0.21320000",
    "close": "0.21320000",
    "volume": "0.00000000",
    "timestamp": 1522180500000
},
{
    "open": "0.21320000",
    "high": "0.21320000",
    "low": "0.21320000",
    "close": "0.21320000",
    "volume": "0.00000000",
    "timestamp": 1522180800000
},
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the JSON files in `charts/` are getting updated by an outside process, and your Node script might be trying to read them at the same time they are getting updated.

Comment: can you post the JSON file? (or a good sample of it)

Comment: [
    {
        "open": "0.21320000",
        "high": "0.21320000",
        "low": "0.21320000",
        "close": "0.21320000",
        "volume": "0.00000000",
        "timestamp": 1522180500000
    },

Comment: @robertklep thanks , is there a way around this from happening? cheers

Comment: @tel90 - first of all fix your code to catch the errors, fs.readFileSync throws exception in case of error. You could wrap your json parsing code into try {} catch{} and in case of error just exit and do a setTimeout of 1 second for example to retry

Comment: Your json was not in proper format.

Comment: @tel90 Other way of fixing it is possible if you control the program that is writing the files, you need it to get exclusive lock for file before writing that way this script will not be able to read a partially written file, but it might cause read errors so its is simpler to just retry a bit later.